# React async function is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In one of my components I have the following functions:

```
addNewIndicator(attrs = {}) {
  const value = attrs.value || 'Indicator'
  const type = attrs.type || 'Generic Type'

  this.createIndicator(value).then(
    console.log('Indicator Created.')
  )
}

async createIndicator(value) {
  await this.props.createIndicatorMutation({
    variables: {
      value
    },
    update: (store, { data: { indicator }} ) => {
      const data = store.readQuery({ query: INDICATOR_FEED_QUERY })
      data.indicatorFeed.splice(0, 0, indicator)
      store.writeQuery({
        query: INDICATOR_FEED_QUERY,
        data,
      })
    }
  })
}
```

`addNewIndicator()` is triggered on a button click. When it runs, I get the following error:

> TypeError: this.createIndicator is not a function

It is pointing to this line:

```
this.createIndicator(value).then(
```

I've done quite a bit of Googling, but haven't been able to figure out why this is the case. My understanding is that async functions can be called like that, but perhaps I'm missing something. Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm still learning React!

Also, I created the project using create-react-app and haven't modified it much other than adding some packages. Thanks for any help!

Edit to add how it is called. It is called from a child component props:

```
<Button primary onClick={this.handleAddSelectionClick}>Add Selected As Indicator</Button>
```

and handleAddSelectionClick:

```
handleAddSelectionClick = () => {
  ...snip...
  this.props.addNewIndicator({
    value: new_indicator_str,
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you call this method on the button click

Comment: rectification, it's not specific to React, all Javascript's `async` functions "are not" functions ;) even in a basic script with jQuery, `$.isFunction` will return false.. i guess you can simply wrap all this in a regular wrapper function

Comment: Do you performed the `bind` of those methods?

Comment: I added how the method is called. Binding it has the same effect. @Kaddath I didn't realize that. How would I wrap it in a wrapper function? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to validate that your 2 methods using the same context (`this`) - 
you might need to do something like that in the constructor:

```
this.addNewIndicator = this.addNewIndicator.bind(this);
this.createIndicator = this.createIndicator.bind(this);
```

Comment: Hey this worked! I didn't realize they could use two different contexts of this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You probably just forgot to bind “this”. As you passed `addNewIndicator` as a callback, it lost its context. In this article several methods of binding callbacks are described, with all pros and cons of each.
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html